# Facebook Graph API : 'error_user_msg': 'These photos were already posted.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I want to publish a post on Facebook using Python, provided that the post contains text and multi images, I wrote this code,

```
params = {
    'access_token': 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'format': 'json'
}

image_urls = ['https://example.com/images/tw8qxmjwrb.jpg', 'https://example.com/images/g41oikacph.jpg']

temp_images = []
for url in image_urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as file:
            file.write(response.content)
            temp_image_path = file.name
        temp_images.append(temp_image_path)

uploaded_images = []
for temp_image in temp_images:
    with open(temp_image, 'rb') as file:
        files = {'source': file}
        response = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/PAGE_ID/photos', params=params, files=files)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            tmIMG = {"media_fbid": "{}".format(response.json().get('id'))}
            uploaded_images.append(response.json().get('id'))
        else:
            print('Failed to upload image:', response.json())

for temp_image in temp_images:
    os.remove(temp_image)

args = {
    "message": "HELLO WORLD.",
    "attached_media[0]": json.dumps({"media_fbid": uploaded_images[0]}),
    "attached_media[1]": json.dumps({"media_fbid": uploaded_images[1]}),
    "published": True
}

response = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/PAGE_ID/feed', params=params, data=args)

print(response.status_code, response.json())
```

but I get this error : **error': 'message': 'Invalid parameter', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'error_subcode': 1366051, 'is_transient': False, 'error_user_title': 'Already Posted', 'error_user_msg': 'These photos were already posted.**

Simply, I want to publish a post on my facebook page that contains text and multi images, how can I do that using python ?

**SOLVED**: The solution is simply to set published:False when uploading single images

```
params['published'] = False;
```

Comment: Okay, so that error message seems pretty clear -- you already uploaded those images (perhaps from a previous run of this code, or perhaps manually), and facebook won't let you upload the same ones again. What is your actual question?

Comment: Simply, I want to publish a post on my facebook page that contains text and multi images, how can I do that using python ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error traceback message, so we can see exactly what line of code is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: The solution is simply to set published:False when uploading single images

```
params['published'] = False;
```